# C++ - Sorting first and second of a vector of pair at the same time

Tags: c++, sorting

```
vector<pair<int, char>> pair_vec;
```

I have such a vector containing pairs. I'd like to sort second of pair in descending order, and if there are two pairs with the same value of `char`, those two should be then sorted by first of pair of ascending order.

```
sort(pair_vec.begin(), pair_vec.end(), sortbysecdesc);
```

This is the code I used to sort the vector. But it can only sort it solely based on second of pair.

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,char> &a, const pair<int,char> &b) {
       return a.second > b.second;
}
```

This is the driver function I used. How do I code to sort the vector by first in ascending order if a few seconds are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this-

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,char> &a, const pair<int,char> &b) {
       if(a.second==b.second)
            return a.first<b.first;
       return a.second > b.second;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the `second` values compare equal, and if so then return the result of comparing the `first` values instead, otherwise return the result of comparing the `second` values:

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,char> &a, const pair<int,char> &b) {
    return (a.second == b.second) ? (a.first < b.first) : (a.second > b.second);
}
```

For example:

```
vector<pair<int, char>> pair_vec{ {1,'a'}, {2,'b'}, {3,'b'}, {4,'b'}, {5,'f'}, };
sort(pair_vec.begin(), pair_vec.end(), sortbysecdesc);
for (auto &p : pair_vec)
    cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << endl;
```

Output:

```
5 f
2 b
3 b
4 b
1 a
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mSb6bp)

Answer (score 2):

Change your binary function to

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,char> &a, const pair<int,char> &b) {
    return (a.second == b.second) ? a.first < b.first : a.second > b.second;
}
```